# Set Time value with a default time

Tags: datetime, time

I created a time field with a default time value below. If I go to the record and I create/edit/view the record, the Time field does not show the default value. Is this default value format correct?

Default Value: TIMEVALUE('08:00:00')

Answer (score 1):

You missed the milliseconds. [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_using_date_datetime.htm):

> Format your text as “HH:MM:SS.MS” on a 24-hour clock

In order to fix it you should change the formula to: `TIMEVALUE("08:00:00.000")`